# How to trace CreateVolume-Gp2 API call in Cost Explorer?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am confused if EBS volumes are really created. This API call is showing as a daily expenses and is costing significantly according to AWS Cost Explorer. Is there a way to trace who made the call?

Answer (score 5):

I tried AWS CloudTrail but this call does not show. It does show in Other Reports as AWS Usage Report in Billing > AWS Cost and Usage Reports.

`CreateVolume-Gp2` is a confusing cost tagging in Cost Explorer if you group by API operation. If you switch to Usage Type, it is tagged as `<some region>-EBS:VolumeUsage.gp2`. I confirmed it somehow equals to the $x per GB-month of provisioned storage cost.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, but it doesn't actually answer OP's question...

Comment: Just chipping in, I think it does answer OP's question -> this answer is saying these aren't "real" CreateVolume API calls / not made by anyone / traceable. The cost is actually coming from regular ol' *usage* of Volumes. I just confirmed that "CreateSnapshot (when grouping by API op)" == [region]-EBS:SnapshotUsage grouping by Usage Type. And that "CreateVolume-gp3" == Sum of [region]-EBS:VolumeP-IOPS.gp3 + [region]-EBS:VolumeUsage.gp3. Costs line up with what I expect out of our volumes usage.

Answer (score 2):

If you came here because you see `CreateVolume-Gp2` charges, but you don't see any volumes, make sure that you look at all **Regions** that might have hiding volumes. I just found one attached to a stopped image that I must have created several years ago. Both were hiding in in `US-West-2` (**Oregon**) which I do not use (because I am East Coast), and did not find until I check all possible Regions.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! On the current Cost Management page, you have the options to filter by regions, but it did not occur to me at first that I have to navigate to a particular region to find the dangling volume.

Answer (score 1):

1. I would also suggest using CloudTrail logs and Athena to determine who created the resources and when.
   https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/find-ebs-user-config-cloudtrail/
2. You could also check EBS volumes from the EC2 console, Dashboard, setting the Region to Global.
3. [How can I list Amazon EBS volume or snapshot information](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ebs-volume-snapshot-ec2-instance/)